# Custom Dialog gives white space at topside in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

i am working on an app , i have implemented a custom dialog for confirmation purpose,I have created a custom layout for the dialog, but it comes with white space at top side, Can someone help me to remove it?
**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_et_selected"
    android:layout_width="300dp" android:layout_height="170dp">

   <RelativeLayout

       android:layout_width="300dp"
       android:layout_height="170dp">
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv_hdr"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:background="#31E2D9"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:text="Report"
           android:textSize="22dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textColor="#ffffff"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="22dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hdr"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:text="Are you sure want to report this post?"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:textColor="#545454"
           android:id="@+id/tv_title" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:weightSum="2"
           >
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="35dp"
               android:text="YES"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>

           <View
               android:layout_width="1dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:background="#ffffff"/>

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="35dp"
               android:text="NO"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textColor="#ffffff"
               android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
               android:layout_weight="1"/>    
       </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that its not an empty dialog title with a blue line right beneath? Don't take that as an insult. Just checking.

Answer (score 8):

i have fixed it by myself,i have removed the dialog header from the code and fixed,please see here.

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_report);
```

Previously it was giving me space for the header which was blank.